# Calling newDArch in darch package

Tags: r

I am reading Learning bayes model with R, and I installed darch package. I get an error when running below code

```
library(darch)

darch <- newDArch(c(2,4,1),batchSize = 2,genWeightFunc = generateWeights)
```

The error is `Error: could not find function "newDArch"`

Can someone help me. Thank!

Comment: when you check ``sessionInfo()`` does ``darch`` appear in your loaded packages?

Comment: Why do you think there should exist a newDArch function???? (I don't see one in hte package Index.)

Comment: This function exists, but is only used internally, see https://github.com/maddin79/darch/blob/master/R/newDArch.R.

Comment: I run sessionInfo() and then see darch_0.12.0.

Comment: How i can call internal function. For instance newDArch. Thank you!